# custom 403 forbidden using rewrite condition

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting, http-status-code-403

If I am banning an IP via a rewrite condition, how can I send them to a custom 403 page?

```
#RewriteRule ^403/?$ 403error.html [NC]
#RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} ^00\.00\.00\.00$
#RewriteRule ^ - [R=403,L]
```

sends it in an endless loop as the ip is denied, however I do not wish to use the default 403 forbidden page. I have a custom page I wish to display. I named it 403error.html and placed it in the top level html directory. How can I deny all but the custom error pages?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the rule is causing an infinite loop error because when a banned ip tries to access the site they are first redirected to 403 page and then the 403 page redirects back to itself causing an endless internal redirects. To solve this, we need to exclude the 403 page or the Rewrite destination from the rule :

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} ^00\.00\.00\.00$
RewriteRule !403error\.html$ /403error.html [L]
```

This will show your custom error page to the banned ip.

Comment: for the win!! again, you are such a great help, Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

I "Patched" my problem temporarily by writing code directly into the ErrorDocument call and referencing/hosting the image needed on a sister domain. However, I would still like to know if it is possible to host the image or html doc within the original domain.

```
ErrorDocument 403 "<body bgcolor=#9C1409><br><br><center><a href=mailto:someone@somewhere.com><img src=http://www.somewhereelse.com/403error.jpg border=0></a></center>"
```